# AWS lambda API ruby responding differently on postman

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, aws-lambda

I am trying to execute some code using AWS lambda using ruby. The same code works well when using configured test event at the lambda function in AWS account, but when I send the same request using postman, it responds with 502 Bad Gateway response code.

When I watch cloudwatch logs, it gives an error message that is not possible on the code that is run.

```
require "payment_notification_response.rb"
Dir["payment_gateway/*.rb"].each {|file| require file }

class PaymentNotificationRequest
    attr_accessor :headers, :body, :query_params, :http_method, :payment_gateway
    PAYMENT_GATEWAYS = [::PaymentGateway]

    def initialize(event)
        self.headers = event["headers"] rescue {}
        self.body = JSON.parse(event['body'].to_json, symbolize_names: true) rescue {}
        self.query_params = event['queryStringParameters'] rescue {}
        self.http_method = event["requestContext"]["http"]["method"] rescue {}
        self.payment_gateway = self.find_payment_gateway_by_request
    end

    def find_payment_gateway_by_request
        PAYMENT_GATEWAYS.each do |pg|
            return pg if pg.new(self).is_the_requester?
        end
    end
    
    def process
        return self.payment_gateway.new(self).process
    end
    
end
```

Below error is triggered at cloudwatch

```
{
    "errorMessage": "undefined method `new' for [PaymentGateway]:Array",
    "errorType": "Function<NoMethodError>",
    "stackTrace": [
        "/var/task/payment_notification_request.rb:23:in `process'",
        "/var/task/lambda_function.rb:7:in `lambda_handler'"
    ]
}
```

How is this possible? Can anyone please help?

Comment: I'd suspect that you get a different response as the requests are in fact also different! Do you have the raw request from postman for comparison?

Comment: https://www.diffchecker.com/HrIpcuAk Here's a diff link, there is hardly any difference. left side is postman, right side is test request at lambda

Comment: The bodies are indeed close enough not to matter. Is it because you're repeating the same request, and it's failing validation for some reason, causing the response to be different?

The "undefined method" error message is thrown due to the response not being as expected: if I were you, I'd add some validation for type etc, before trying to use it.

Comment: ```self.payment_gateway``` The error is saying that code in process method is having array which is not the case, it should be having PaymentGateway class